# django __init__.py need to read database after migrate

Tags: python, django

I have a django projet: `mysite`

I have a setting in **mysite/mysite/__init__.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

And the **celery.py** will need to read database

```
app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'calculate': {
        'task': 'test.tasks.calculate',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=get_db_setting()),
    }
}
```

And I face a problem.
On a whole new server,we need to migrate to create tables :`python manage.py migrate`

But the `__init__.py` will also execute,and it raise error because it can't find the table in database

What's a better way to colve this problem??

Comment: python manage.py makemigration and then python manage.py migrate

Comment: Put the import into the modules where they are actually needed. In general, don't run application logic from `__init__.py`. Just put there what is needed to initialize the package, not the application.

Comment: needing to get config values from the db is bad architecture, would be better to use environment variables (see http://12factor.net/).  either way you need to provide a default in your code (via try/except if you insist on using a db which may not be available) in case the config can't be accessed

Comment: @KlausD. because I want to initial it when django runserver